# iOS 13 NSAttributedString not working properly inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsattributedstring

This issue occurs only in iOS 13. First time `UITableViewCell` is showed font and color will be from storyboard while the text is from attributed string. When the cell is reused, it will take font and color from atributed string.

This is my code in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let message = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(name): \(messageBody))", attributes: lastMessageAttributes)
    message.addAttributes(senderLastMessageAttributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: name.count + 1))
}
```

I have tried also

```
let message = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(name):)", attributes: lastMessageAttributes)
message.append(NSAttributedString(string: messageBody, attributes: senderLastMessageAttributes))
```

also this

```
let message = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(name):)", attributes: lastMessageAttributes)
message.append(NSAttributedString(string: messageBody, attributes: senderLastMessageAttributes))
let newMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: message)
```

If I do not add any attributed it is working, like this:

```
let message = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(name): \(messageBody))", attributes: lastMessageAttributes)
```

Comment: where are you assigning your AttributedString to your label?

Comment: In tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath)

Comment: @Markicevic I am also facing same issue. Please let me know if you fixed this..

Comment: @SureshVutukuru i added setting message to DispatchQueue.

Comment: I have answered your question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316790/nsattributedstring-not-working-as-expected-in-ios-13/59244234#59244234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a bug, issue was somewhere else in the code.